# Col row with dict python on excel

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have this code :

```
"result": [{
        "Name": "Jean",
        "LastName": "xxx",
        "Salaire": xxx,
        "hire": "2015-07-25",
        "numerobadge": 0000111 ",
        "worked_per_week": 35,
    }, {
        "Name": "Catherine",
        "LastName": "xxx",
        "Salaire": xxx,
        "hire": "2016-11-09",
        "numerobadge": 0000127 ",
        "worked_per_week": 25,
    }, {
        "Name": "George",
        "LastName": "xxx",
        "Salaire": xxx,
        "hire": "2016-12-05",
        "numerobadge": 0000144 ",
        "worked_per_week": 35,
    },
```

I want to extract `hours_per_week` and `name` on excel. I don't find a good tutorial with dict and list and xlsxwriter.

Comment: Post the python code you have tried, not just the JSON you are trying to parse.

Answer (score 1):

The result is a list and you can extract the information by a loop like:

```
for p in result:
    name = p['Name']
    w_p_w = p['worked_per_week']
```

Comment: How i can extract values ? when i lunch only in console i have the result

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses01.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

"result":[
{ "Name":"Jean", "LastName":"xxx", "Salaire":xxx, "hire":"2015-07-25", "numerobadge":0000111", "worked_per_week":35, }, { "Name":"Catherine", "LastName":"xxx", "Salaire":xxx, "hire":"2016-11-09", "numerobadge":0000127", "worked_per_week":25, }, { "Name":"George", "LastName":"xxx", "Salaire":xxx, "hire":"2016-12-05", "numerobadge":0000144", "worked_per_week":35, },
]
row = 0

col = 0

    a=['result']

    for p in result
        name = p['Name']
        w_p_w = p['worked_per_week']


workbook.close()
```